# VBA Excel if statement for removing shapes with ID like something

Tags: excel, vba

I have more than 1 shape called "Picture..." in my active workbook.

I want to remove it along with the other shapes, which have their specified IDs~

Since there is no problem with them, because they have an unique ID, I have problem with them two, called "Picture...".

My code looks like this:

```
 Sub ImgFullRemove3()
 Dim Pic As Picture
 Dim PicName As String, PicName2 As String, PicName3 As String
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  PicName = "Cable_Number"
  PicName2 = "Divider"
  PicName3 = "*Picture*"

  For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
  Debug.Print Pic.Name
    If Pic.Name = PicName Or PicName2 Or PicName3 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Cable_Number").Delete
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Divider").Delete
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("*Picture*").Delete
    End If
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

It returns nothing, similarily to the another one below:

```
  Sub ImgFullRemove()
  Dim Img As Picture
  Dim ImgName As String
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each Img In ActiveSheet.Pictures
  Debug.Print Img.Name
  If Img.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Delete
  End If
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub
```

that refers only to these "Pictures..." objects. The result is exactly the same.

How can I make this code running properly?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification to your first sample code that I think will achieve your desired outcome.

```
PicName = "Cable_Number"
PicName2 = "Divider"
PicName3 = "*Picture*"

For Each pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
  If pic.Name = PicName Or _
      pic.Name = PicName2 Or _
      pic.Name Like PicName3 Then
          pic.Delete
  End If
Next
```

Note: you can't use `If` in the way you'd tried - i.e if `A = X, Y or Z`.

You have to test if `A = X or A = Y or A = Z`.

Comment: Still not working. Result exactly the same: No errors, code is being executed but no results at all

Comment: I notice you've got an `On Error Resume Next` in your code. Remove that and chances are that will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Done. Now debugger is saying: Type mismatch
Line: For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures

Comment: That's odd. It works when I test it (with images copy/pasted onto a sheet). Is Excel definitely finding a `ActiveSheet`? Try fully qualifying the sheet with `Workbooks("yourworkbookname").Sheets("thesheetname").Pictures`

Comment: I tried all
Now the type mismatch is pointing the "Next" line